# Unix script to check the directory of a user entered file and print its directory

Tags: shell, unix

I need to make an Unix script to check the directory of a user entered file and print its directory. For e.g. user entered a filename "abc.txt" then unix will search its directory and will print it on the screen through echo.

Comment: What do you mean by its not working.

Comment: consider editting your question to show a small sample directory, your required output, what you are currently typing, and what your current output is. As is, you're expecting us to read your mind about what you need to do. Just show us! :-!)  (use 4 spaces at the beginning of each line of sample data so dir listings etc will keep their formatting). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It will print the absolute path:

> find $PWD -name 'filename'

Comment: You have to escape `backtick` either indent four spaces or use double `backtick`